# Linux Mint 19.3 - chgrp/chown not working?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, chown, chgrp

[image]

My apologies if I'm missing something obvious, but this is driving me nuts.  I'm just trying to set up an sftp server and give the user group permissions on the folder indicated above by changing the group to sftp on the folder I want to share.  I thought what I did above would accomplish that, but as is seen from the ls command, the group remains unchanged.  The command even took some time and I heard the drive reading.

The only factor I can imagine mattering is it's an ntfs internal drive.  I successfully auto mounted it on startup (fstab) to that Hitachi6TB folder.  However, I did this successfully before and maybe I'm forgetting something, but meh.

Anyone able to tell me what's amiss there?

Comment: You are correct, it is NTFS mounted with FUSE probably

Comment: Look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389990/chown-not-working-in-mounted-partition